# PageRef or ActionMethod problem

Tags: visualforce, commandbutton, actionfunction, actionsupport

I'm trying to add functionality to a JQuery mobile app someone else wrote and encountering problems with either the action method or the page reference class when trying to construct another page to appear in the App. I know it has to be something simple that I'm overlooking, but can't seem to quite nail it.

Here's the relevant portions of the code (far to much to post all of it).

VF Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="SiteVisit"
    showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="true">

        <apex:actionFunction action="{!goToLogACall}"
            name="goToLogACall">
        </apex:actionFunction>

        <!-- Start of first page: #one -->
        <div data-role="page" id="one">

                    <--- working code skipped --->

                        <!--- ### Problem Section --->
                        <!-- Open Log A Call -->
                        <apex:outputPanel id="Open_LogACall" rendered="{!IF(ISBLANK(ClientId), false, true)}">
                            <a href="#" data-role="button" onclick="$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(); goToLogACall()" reRender="Open_Log_A_Call" >Log A Call</a>
                        </apex:outputPanel>
                        <!--- ### End Problem Section ### --->

                    <--- more working code skipped --->

            </div>
            <!-- /page one -->

</apex:page>
```

Custom Controller Method:

```
public PageReference goToLogACall()
{

    System.debug('---> goToLogACall: ' + customerId + ' ' + clientId  );

    showLogACall = true;

    ShowBackButton = true;        

    //PageReference ReturnPageURL = getRetURL();

    PageReference pr = page.Log_A_Call;

    if ( clientMap != null && clientMap.keySet().size() > 0 )
    {
        currentClient = clientMap.get(clientId );
    }

    if(currentClient != null) currentClientName = currentClient.Name;

    cstmrParentId = customer.Parent_Customer__c;

    cstmrPrntName = getcstmrParentName(cstmrParentId); 

    pr.getParameters().put('Id',customerId);
    pr.getParameters().put('customer',customerId);
    pr.getParameters().put('currentClient',clientId);
    pr.getParameters().put('cstmrParent',cstmrParentId);
    pr.getParameters().put('currentClientName',currentClientName);
    pr.getParameters().put('cstmrPrntName',cstmrPrntName);

    pr.setRedirect(false); 
    System.debug('---> returning: ' + pr);

    return pr;  
}
```

At the moment, I'm getting this error message:

> The value of the "id" parameter contains a character that is not allowed or the value exceeds the maximum allowed length. Remove the character from the parameter value or reduce the value length and resubmit.

Prior to this, I had tried setting the problem section as a CommandButton and was receiving "ERROR: Formula Expression is required on the action attributes" which can mean a huge number of things including that the reRender attribute hasn't been set properly. I know I'm not doing something correctly.

The code I was using for that is below:

```
    <apex:commandButton action="{!goToLogACall}" value="Log A Call"
                    onclick="$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();" reRender="OpenLog_A_Call" >                        
    </apex:commandButton>
```

What I want is for the page reference `pr` to render in `<apex:outputPanel id="Open_LogACall">`. How do I replace the button with the page reference being returned? Do I just need to set the redirect to true instead of false? What am I missing here?

Comment: Debug customerId to see what it has ?

Comment: Also is customerId an Account ID ?If its person Account may be its complaining that ID is invalid because your standard controller is Account ?

Comment: CustomerId is an Account. It has a value. ClientId is an account. It also has a value. Neither are person Accounts. They're just different record types. Have looked at this in Dev Mode and see appropriate values in the controller.

Comment: If customerId is actually an Account, you must use customerId.Id - you cannot put Account objects into the Id Parameter of a VF-Page.

Comment: It's expecting an Id for an Account. CustomerId is the Id for the "customer" type Account on the page. There are several different Accounts referenced on the same page. The 2nd is "currentClient" and the last is "cstmrParent" which is an "ultimate" parent, not a direct parent. I don't think all of the params I've used are needed for this page which is what my debugging is showing at present, particularly Id and customer.

Comment: Your code is *definitely* incorrect, and just about anything you try to do will fail. You absolutely cannot render a PageReference into an outputPanel. It's not built to do that. And, any other basic attempt to render the page using Visualforce within the page dynamically will result in a hilarious, but not-very-useful, way (the exact hilarity depends on the way you attempt). What you *want* is probably a component, or possibly by using templates/composites. Or simply redirect to the new page entirely.

Comment: On the surface, your code *should* work, but the error you're getting simply means you've written code that somehow tricked Visualforce into loading its view state into an ID parameter (I've managed to trigger this before, almost completely by accident; it's never fun, and I can never seem to intentionally repeat it later). I wrote a basic version of your page, and it works in terms of redirecting to the new page while including parameters, called from an actionFunction. That's not your problem.

Comment: @sfdcfox. Thanks. I solved the issue earlier today. I don't need a pageref at all. My "destination" code needs to be included in the originating page. A boolean variable `showLogACall` turns the visibility on when the action fuction fires. I have a diff method to turn it off when closing that "page" in what was intended to be a quasi-single page jquery mobile app I've been adding functionality to. The original author had tons of pagerefs which I mistakenly thought I also needed. He left behind pages for each method that aren't used. That confused & misdirected me.

Comment: Should we close this as off topic? The OP doesn't really have enough code here to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @AdrianLarson. Since I've solved the issue, it doesn't matter to me although I'm not certain whether you can close a question that has an open bounty on it.